# Url Encode javascript object literal

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, url

I have Model

```
public class SomeModel
{
    public string SomeText { get; set; }
}
```

In javascript I make an javascript object literal of the model:

```
var model = {
                SomeText: "test"
            };
var serializedData = JSON.stringify(model);
```

This makes a string which looks like the following:

```
"{"SomeText":"test"}"
```

Now suppose I want to send this model to a controller which accepts a model like this with the following function:

```
public void Index(SomeModel model)
{
}
```

What I need is an url string in which the model has the following form:

```
"?SomeText=test"
```

I know that ajax does exactly this when you send the model via ajax post:

```
$.ajax({type:"POST", 
        url: "someUrl", 
        data: serializedData,
        ...
});
```

The 'data:' url-encodes the serialized data.

But I actually do not want to use ajax, so I need to build this url myself. I want to do exactly the same thing as ajax does with 'data:'. How can I url-encode the serialized data myself?

Comment: Check out  http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You should use [`jQuery.param`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/):

```
$.param({foo:'bar', fizz:'buzz'});
//produces foo=bar&fizz=buzz
```

---

Arrays are ok too:

```
$.param({foo:['bar', 'baz']});
//produces foo%5B%5D=bar&foo%5B%5D=baz
//which is the url encoded form of: foo[]=bar&foo[]=baz
```

if you need the traditional array syntax, use the second parameter:

```
$.param({foo:['bar','baz']}, true);
//produces foo=bar&foo=baz
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed, thank you, but I need to check further because the model contains a list actually...

Answer (score -2):

To escape a single value, Javascript has the function `escape`.  You must provide your own function to iterate through the object, add the keys, and so on.

**EDIT**

Esailija is kind enough to remind me that `escape` does not handle many common cases properly, and `encodeURIComponent` is much better.  If you're already using jQuery (and you should be), zzzzBov's answer is better still.